# QTextBlockUserDataの使い方

Tags: python, python3, qt

いつもお世話になっております。
`QTextBlockUserData`についてお聞きしたいのですが、
割注と、縦中横の実現をしてみたいな～と思っています。
PySideのText系のクラスで、最後に怪しいと思っている
もので、これが自在に操れるようになればいいな～と思
っています。
　[Programming Talk-QTextBlockUserData](http://nullege.com/codes/search/PyQt4.QtGui.QTextBlockUserData)
カスタム系では珍しくサンプルコードなどがある分野です。
　`QTextBlock`で、独自のユーザー定義のブロックをセット
できるようです。
　[QTextBlock setUserData](http://pyside.github.io/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QTextBlock.html)
 ここに書いてある具体例は、仮に私がプログラミングエディタを
作成している場合、統合された開発環境をセットするべく、デバッガ
をセットしたいとき、その行（ブロック）を、ブレークポイントにする
という独自の設定を行い、セットできるという話のようです。
　つまり、コンピューターが、そのブロックはブレークポイントだ、
と判定できるようにするという、確かに他の要素にはない独自の判断要素
をセットできるようです。(ブール型でもできそうな気がする？）
　以前の質問より、割注や縦中横を実装したいと思っていますが、これらは
どちらも、`QTextBlock`に関係した物だろうと思います。
　ここで、独自のブロックを作成すれば、割注や縦中横を実装できないかな
と思っています。
　現在、このブロックは、特殊な判定をプログラムに行わせるものなのだな。
という程度で、ブロックのいわば、ブール系の要素を行うためのもので、
ブロックそのものの態様（１本のラインで２行分とか、縦書きとか）を変える事
ができるものだとはなんとなく思っていません。少し手ほどきをしていただけま
せんか。お願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ブロックの考え方等、`QTextDocument`のデータ(コンテンツ)構造は[Rich Text Document Structure](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/richtext-structure.html)の文書が参考になると思います。

ここには、`QTextBlock`は(文字通り)テキストの1ブロックを表すもの、とあります。
「ブロック」の単位をどう定義するかは実装者(プログラマ)次第なので、「割中」や「縦中横」の部分を「ブロック」とするならば、その付加情報として`QTextBlockUserData`を紐付けるのは有効な考え方と思います。(`QTextBlockUserData`は`QTextBlock`に対し1:1の情報であるので)

なお、`QTextBlockUserData`は何もメソッドを持たないクラス(インターフェース)なので、`QTextBlock`に自動的に作用する要素はないようです。適切なサブクラスを定義し、アプリケーションが付加情報の読み書きをする必要があるようです。

Comment: そうおっしゃられると、心強いです。とりあえず、どんなコードにすればいいのかまだわからないので、サンプルコードを直輸入して、反応を確かめていきたいと思います。

Comment: すいません。ちょっと確認したいのですが、「`QTextBlockUserData`は、何もメソッドを持たないインターフェースなので、`QTextBlock`に自動的に作用する要素はないようです。」とあります。つまり、`QTextBlockUserData`は、インターフェース同様、それ自体が実体となるものではなく、橋渡し的な役割をするものだ。とりあえず最初は、データ（メソッド処理）格納庫みたいなもので、実際は、それを`QTextBlock.setUserData()`で、セットした後、自動的に作用するのではなく、改めて手動でメソッドを置いたり、データを取り出したりして、ガチャガチャと`QTextBlock`などにその内容を及ぼす必要があるということですね？それが、「アプリケーションが付加情報の読み書きをする必要がある」ということですね。?恥ずかしいことに、サンプルコード見ても、こりゃ何をしてるんだよくわからんというのが素直な感想でした。

Comment: Haruさんのコメントのとおりの意図の回答です。ちなみに、`QTextBlockUserData`を使っている既存実装には`QSyntaxHilighter`がありますが、そのドキュメントにも同様のことが書いてあります。

Comment: 使い方に関しての質問なので、上の答えがベストだと思いますので、これで締めます。ありがとうございました。